# PowerPoint presentation with C# and PowerPoint Viewer

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm able to execute a powerpoint presentation using the following code:

```
static public class PowerPointManager
{
    static private Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application app; 
    static private Presentations ppts;

    static PowerPointManager()
    {
        app = new ApplicationClass();            
        app.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        ppts = app.Presentations;
    }

    static public void LoadPPT(string pptPath)
    {
        Presentation ppt = ppts.Open(pptPath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
        SlideShowSettings sss = ppt.SlideShowSettings;
        sss.Run();

        while (app.SlideShowWindows.Count <= 0) ;

        SlideShowWindow ssw = ppt.SlideShowWindow;
        SlideShowView ssv = ssw.View;
    }
}
```

that code works fine while i have a full PowerPoint application installed at my PC.
Now, what i want to do is to execute powerpoint presentations using the PowerPoint Viewer instead of the full PowerPoint application.
So, if i execute the code above with just a PowerPoint Viewer installed at my system, it throws a "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" at the "app = new ApplicationClass();" line.

Is it possible to use the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint" library with the PowerPoint Viewer? If not, are there any other libraries to control a PowerPoint presentation that work properly with the Viewer version?

Thank you.

Comment: The last version of the PP viewer that supported automation was the 2000 version..

Comment: So full PowerPoint is the only solution?

Comment: Have you tried [using command line arguments](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Command-line-switches-for-PowerPoint-2007-and-the-PowerPoint-Viewer-2007-205f1460-098e-42ba-bc6c-310a43d8a2cc#bm5) on the viewer?

Comment: Yes, that way maybe i could start a presentation with the viewer, but not control it, so the idilical solution would be to also have a reference to the presentation to implement "next", "previous", and so on within my C# code; i mean, to be able to use the interop.powerpoint or any other COM interface to the PowerPoint Viewer.